How does the sun prostrate?
I read the hadith Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3227:

Narrated Abu Dharr: "I entered the Masjid when the sun had set, and
the Prophet (ﷺ) was sitting. He said: 'O Abu Dharr! Do you know where
this goes?' I said: 'Allah and His Messenger know better.' He said:
'Indeed it goes to seek permission to prostrate, so it is permitted.
And it is as if it has been said to it: "Rise from its setting place.'
Then he recited: 'That is its fixed course.'" He said: "That is the
recitation of 'Abdullah bin Mas'ud."

Is there any known explanation of this hadith given we think we know that when the sun is setting in one place, it is rising in another (earth goes round the sun).
